# How to load model for inference?

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, deep-learning, pytorch

I am using a simple perceptron based classifier to generate sentiment analysis in Pytorch, complete code here [Classifying Yelp Reviews](https://github.com/joosthub/PyTorchNLPBook/blob/master/chapters/chapter_3/3_5_Classifying_Yelp_Review_Sentiment.ipynb).

The example does sentiment analysis, it outputs if the given input string is positive or negative.

> example: this is a pretty small old great book -> positive

The application stores the final model along with the vectorizer.json.

So my question is: What should be the pre-requisites to build a separate application just to test the model, so that it can be used in web-application later-on?

Below is my current understanding and queries for this:

I assume to test, we need to load the model, load model parameters and evaluate for inference, please confirm

```js
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs) # Model class must be defined somewhere
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval() # run if you only want to use it for inference
```

Once step 1 is done, I hope we can deploy the model using Flask and expose a REST API for model inference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice tutorial explaining how to load model for inference, here is the link

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_models_for_inference.html

Thanks!